# Doctrine 2: Building a nested array tree from a self-refrencing Entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have an Entity that looks like this:

```
class Privilege
{
/**
 * @Id @Column(type="bigint")
 * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @Column(type="string",length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @Column(type="string",length=255)
 */
private $slug;

/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Privilege", mappedBy="parent")
 */
private $children;

/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Privilege", inversedBy="children")
 * @JoinColumn(name="p_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $parent;
```

If a  `Privilege Entity` does not have a parent, the field is NULL. I have a basic query like this:

```
    $qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('p')
        ->from('\Dashboard\Entity\Privilege', 'p')
        ->andWhere('p.parent IS NULL');

    $q = $qb->getQuery();
    $privileges = $q->getResult();
```

I would like the array result I return from this method to look similar to this:

```
root1:
    child1:
        subchild1a
        subchild2a
   child2:
        subchild1b
        subchild2b
        subchild3b
            subsubchild1b
   child3:
        subchild1c
root2:
....
....
```

Is there a way to HYDRATE the results from Doctrine 2 so it builds the array results this way? If not, how would you build this array? I am still playing around with Doctrine 2, and I noticed each element in my `$privileges` array has a `$privilege->getChildren()` which returns a `PersistentCollection`, obviously not the actual record.

If I have to build this nested tree myself (ie: no built in way in Doctrine to do it), how do I turn this `PersistentCollection` returned into the actual data so I can build some sort of recursive method to build it for me? I am looking through the docs, but obviously in the wrong place.

Comment: The first thing to do is check the SQL that Doctrine is generating and see if it is returning all the rows that it should.

Comment: It is. I am looking for a way to HYDRATE a nested tree in doctrine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results are already in a nested tree. The `PersistentCollection` can be iterated as if it was an array:

```
foreach($parent->getChildren() as $child) {
    // $child is an instance of Privilige
}
```

Still you should try `$privileges = $q->getArrayResult();` and see if that gives a result you would prefer.

Comment: I just haven't had time to go back in test this. But I believe you :)

Comment: it is containing all the hierarchy, but it is getting each child with a new query for me.. advices?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is called "One-To-Many self-referenced association" in documentation: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-self-referencing

Here's code for hierarchy of categories from the docs:

```
<?php
/** @Entity **/
class Category
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="parent")
     **/
    private $children;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="children")
     * @JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $parent;
    // ...

    public function __construct() {
        $this->children = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

"This effectively models a hierarchy of categories and from the database perspective is known as an adjacency list approach."

So I think this should do all the job for you, and create the hierarchy of arrays you need.

Since you already have your annotations like in docs, your `$parent->getChildren()` should already contain all the hierarchy, as @rojoca said.