# How to use Repository custom functions in a FormType

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, symfony-2.2

The problem I'm facing is I have to create a selectbox in a form that holds all the parent entities (Category Entity). Now i managed to do this with:

```
$builder->add('parent', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'KprCentarZdravljaBundle:Category',
                'query_builder' => function($repository) use ($param, $catID) { 
                                        return $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
                                                ->where('p.id != :id AND p.parent = :parent')
                                                ->setParameters(array('id' => $param, 'parent' => $catID));},
                'property' => 'name',
                'required' => false,
                'attr'   =>  array('data-placeholder' => '--Izaberite Opciju--'),
                ));
```

As u can see i pass 2 arguments first is the current category.id(a category cant be its own parent) and a second which is a parent id, because i want all the children from that parent. This works nice but it doesn't give me the parents children's children.
I created a CategoryRepository with a recursive function that returns all the children:

```
<?php

namespace Kpr\CentarZdravljaBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Kpr\CentarZdravljaBundle\Entity\Category;

class CategoryRepository extends EntityRepository
{
public function findByParenting($parent)
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb->add('select', 'cat')
       ->add('from', 'KprCentarZdravljaBundle:Category cat')
       ->add('where', 'cat.parent = :parent')
       ->setParameter('parent', $parent);
    // $qb instanceof QueryBuilder
    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $results = $query->getResult();
    foreach($results as $result){
        if($result->getParent()){
            $newResult = $this->findByParenting($result->getId());
            $results = array_merge($results, $newResult);
        }
    }
    return $results;

}
}
```

How can I use the findByParenting($parent) function in a entity field?

Comment: Anyone? I really need help :(...

Comment: I asked another question in which i made some progress here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16463926/symfony2-choice-field-not-working

Comment: Did you try replacing the content of your 'function($repository)...' in the form type with 'return $repository->findByParenting(...)'?

Comment: Yea tried that and i got the following error "Expected argument of type "Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder", "array" given". This is why I wanted the choice field, because i supply the result with findByParenting(...), I cant return a query builder instance

Comment: Hmm, that is rather irritating. Perhaps you could pass the entity manager into the form type on construction and set the choices option of the entity field directly to the result of findByParenting()?

Comment: Aaaaaaa I MAde IT WORK!!!! Thanks man, the answer was so easy, I'll post the full answer in the post mentioned on my second comment. You helped me by pointing out the choices option of an entity field. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the answer: [Symfony2 choice field not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16463926/symfony2-choice-field-not-working/16478110#16478110). Thanks [redbirdo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/302002/redbirdo).

Comment: You could have just returned the query builder from your repository and used that in your form type...

Comment: Actually i couldn't because findByParenting($parent) is a recursive function that gets all of the children from $parent and their children and so on, puts them in an array and returns the result.

Comment: Why would you need to do that when Doctrine takes care of that for you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6391807/206546

Comment: So how do I solve my problem? I return a querybuilder from my repository and load this querybuilder into my entity field and my field gets populated by the first level children only. I allready tried this... And this linked answer you sent, first: using getArrayReslut() returns only the first level children, second: using foreach $parent->getChildren() as $child doesent solve my problem because i dont know how many levels I must dig, there could be 100 levels, that's why I use a recursive function.

Comment: Then I guess the answer you have accepted is the right one for you.  Your case seems quite extreme however, and I wanted to provide the simpler answer as a footnote for those who do not have 100s of nested levels (zoiks)

Answer (score 0):

You are having this error because you have to return the QueryBuilder object on your `findByParenting($parent)` function

```
public function findByAllocation($alloc) 
    {
      return $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
               ->select('r')
               ->where('r.showRangeStart < :alloc', 'r.showRangeStop >= :alloc')
               ->setParameter('alloc', $alloc)
               ;

    }
```